# Disable maximizing WPF window on double click on the caption

Tags: wpf, window, double-click, wndproc, maximize

**How to disable maximizing WPF window on double click on the caption and leave resizing available?**

---

I know that *ResizeMode* disables maximizing, but it also prevents resizing the form

```
ResizeMode="CanMinimize"
```

I know how to remove maximize and minimize buttons, but it's still possible to maximize by double click on the caption.

In WinForms it can be achieved easily. Just set *FormBorderStyle* from *None* to *FixedSingle* or *Fixed3D*. But it's not an option in WPF any more.

---

P.S. I'm trying some tricks with handling WM_GETMINMAXINFO, WM_SYSCOMMAND, etc. But [seems it's not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18707977/968003)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*WPF* does not have a native way to disable maximizing windows (unlike *WinForms*). Hence consider the following key points:

**1. Hide the Maximize button**

Using *WinAPI* is a way to go, but only for hiding the Maximize button. Use the following:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

private const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
private const int WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 0x10000;

private void Window_SourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper((Window)sender).Handle;
    var value = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
    SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, (int)(value & ~WS_MAXIMIZEBOX));
}
```

**2. Handling maximizing manually**

That code above still allows maximizing (e.g. by double click on the window's title).

*WPF* has no control on the title bar behavior. if you want to change the double click behavior you will need to remove the title bar and create you own. Take a look how it's been done in [MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/) - [link to sample](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Themes/MetroWindow.xaml). After that handle double click event.

Answer (score 9):

Good solution I put together with a little help from MSDN on detecting non-client mouse activity in WPF windows.

Calling `handled = true` in the `WndProc` if `msg == WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK` will prevent the window from maximizing when the user double clicks on the non-client area.

```
myClass()  //c'tor
{
  InitializeComponent();
  SourceInitialized += new EventHandler(myClass_SourceInitialized);  
}

void myClass_SourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource source = System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.FromHwnd(new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
    source.AddHook(new System.Windows.Interop.HwndSourceHook(WndProc));
}

int WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK { get { return 0x00A3; } }

private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    if (msg == WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK)
    {
        handled = true;  //prevent double click from maximizing the window.
    }

    return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

Helpful MSDN ref:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f54dde25-b748-4724-a7fe-a355b086cfd4/mouse-event-in-the-nonclient-window-area

Comment: @Klaus - I know it's been a while, but this might help you (for the future!).

Comment: The only truly effective option I've found so far.  All other have been limited, or hacks, or just plain ineffective.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue. My window does not have any form border or title bar, but it can be moved around (using the mouse). The problem is that if a user moves the window to the top edge of the screen, then Windows automatically maximizes the window.

I managed to work around this issue by attaching the following handler to the window's `StateChanged` event.

```
private void OnWindowStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
    {
        this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is clunky because the window maximizes momentarily then restores back down giving an ugly visual response.

Answer (score 2):

After encountering this problem and researching this SO question I decided that the answers were not sufficient. After removing the Title Bar the window still maximizes when double clicking close to the top of the window.

I chose the approach of removing the title bar and disabling double clicking on the window.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MouseDoubleClick += (sender, args) =>
        {
            args.Handled = true;
        };
    }
}
```

In my application I was using MahApps.Metro which would inherit from **MetroWindow** instead of **Window** however the above example should work in both cases.

Comment: `PreviewMouseDoubleClick` is better option, `MouseDoubleClick` is not working always

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
    public MainWindow()
   {

    InitializeComponent();
    this.SizeChanged += MainWindow_SizeChanged;
   }    
    void MainWindow_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {

      if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
      {
       this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
      }


}
}
```

Comment: It doesn't disable maximizing actually and leads to blinking window. Hence I can't mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple (but ugly) solution:

```
// inside a Window class
protected override void OnPreviewMouseDoubleClick(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreviewMouseDoubleClick(e);

    const int titleHeight = 30;
    var position = e.GetPosition(this);

    if (position.Y <= titleHeight)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Note: The user can still maximizing the window using the contextmenu on the title bar / moving the window to the upper edge of the screen.

Comment: it might be ugly, yet it is the best solution, because it doesn't require a WINAPI import and it doesnt flicker. Good job